# What does string builder do?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, stringbuilder

what string builder command do in the asp.net cs file.

Comment: ... it builds strings?

Comment: Microsoft were even so kind as to write an entire article on the subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: I've just had a look through your questions thus far. Please for the love of the Gods read through this when you have time: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html You'll get your questions answered much better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a command - it is a class which is part of the [Base Class Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library), in the `System.Text` namespace.

The [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class lets you construct large strings in an efficient manner.

There is a Microsoft artical titled "[Using the StringBuilder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5.aspx)" that explains how to use this class.

Answer (score 6):

It's a way to build strings that doesn't create lots of intermediate strings (that then need to be cleaned up by th GC).

Example code (don't do this):

```
string s = "";
for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
   s += "test";
```

Every time you add something to a string, you create a **new** string. The old version is discarded and needs to be collected by the GarbageCollector.

Stringbuilder version:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
{   sb.Append("test"); }
string s = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder is a class available in .net framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

For using StringBuilder you can check this link -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5(VS.71).aspx